# Using Google Fonts in FireFox

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts

I am having some trouble getting a google font to work on my webpages when viewing them with Firefox. Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Lobster">
    <title>Page Title</title>
   </head>
<body>      
    <p style="font-family:Lobster">Hi, this is some test text! </p>
</body>
```

I have also installed the font on my pc. The font displays perfectly in Chrome, Safari and IE but not in Firefox. Does Firefox require some additional code to get custom fonts to work ??

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster"> Can you please use this

Comment: Google generates all the tags for you, all you have to do is copy/paste them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the line

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Lobster">`

to

`<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>`

Now it works for me